# Tableau : display aggregate string rows for each category

Tags: filter, aggregate, tableau-api, dimension, tableau-desktop

I have data as below
[image]

For each category, I want to display the last row in the sub category only, ie last() == 0 should be displayed for sub category

Output as below
[image]

Something similar to LOD but only dimensions here

Comment: why there's /US at the end of the rows with ID 2 while rows with ID 1 don't have /North? is it just a typo?

Comment: Yes it was a typo. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that for each ID, you have to check the Last column and, in that "partition", take the related value of subcategory if the value is 0.

```
{ FIXED [ID] : MAX(if [Last] = 0 then [Subcategory] end)}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response, One other thing I have to mention is Last() is a function, so when i used the fixed, it says "Argument to max (an aggregate function) is already an aggregation and cannot be further aggregated.

Comment: what0s the logic behind Last()? I mean, what does it "show" in your scenario? alppahbetical order or anything else?

Comment: I used first() , previous_value() to aggregate subcategory string data to get the last row in each sub category. Now I want to display the last row for all rows ie display last() == 0 for all the sub category rows. This is to show, for any category in a ID, it contains all these subcategories.

Comment: Subcategory:                                                                                                                      if  FIRST() == 0 then MIN([subcategory])
else FIRST() != 0 THEN  PREVIOUS_VALUE("") + "/" + min([subcategory])
end

Comment: Without using function last, is there a way to get the last row in each subcategory?